# Pourquoi « bonne merde» veut dire « bonne chance! »

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

Pourquoi quand on dit « bonne merde », ça veut dire « bonne chance »? Il y a quelque chose qui concerne avec la culture, non?
 je sais que dans la culture d’anglophone, si un oiseau fait caca, c’est porter la chance.

Comment: Une note sur l'extension géographique: "bonne merde" ne s'utilise qu'en Belgique (peut-être également dans le Nord de la France, à confirmer par un locuteur local). En France, on dit "merde" tout court pour souhaiter "bonne chance".

Answer (score 4):

L'expression « bonne merde » est inconnue en France mais courante en Belgique.

Dans le milieu du théâtre, il vaut mieux éviter de dire « bonne chance » à quelqu'un qui s'apprête à monter sur scène car c'est une expression interdite par superstition.

L'usage est de dire « Merde ! » à la place. Une explication pourrait être la suivante :

> Cette expression daterait de l'époque où les spectateurs se faisaient déposer en calèche devant l'entrée, halte au cours de laquelle les chevaux ne manquaient pas de garnir de leur crottin le parvis du théâtre. Cette « garniture » étant directement proportionnelle au nombre de spectateurs, c'était faire preuve de bienveillance que de souhaiter « beaucoup de merdes » aux artistes.

L'usage de dire « Merde ! » ou « Bonne merde ! » s'est étendu à des situations où quelqu'un va se présenter à un examen, passer son permis de conduire, etc.

Sources: [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstition_th%C3%A9%C3%A2trale) et [expressio.fr](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/merde.php)

Comment: "Bonne merde" est souvent utilisé en Belgique (peut-être aussi dans le Nord de la France ?): c'est sans doute un dérivé du "merde" théâtral, par calque avec "bonne chance". A titre personnel, je l'ai entendu et l'entends souvent souhaité aux étudiants avant un examen ou une session d'examens.

Comment: (ajout au commentaire ci-dessus): même la police fédérale belge se permet de souhaiter "bonne merde" sur son compte Twitter officiel, c'est dire si l'expression y est courante ! https://twitter.com/policefederale/status/939117970743283712

Comment: @Greg, merci. Je ne l'avais jamais entendu...

Comment: Je confirme l'usage tout à fait courant de "Bonne merde" en Belgique. Plus ça va et plus je me rends compte des nombreuses (bien que rarement dangereuses) différences entre le français de Belgique et celui de France...

Comment: @LaurentS. Et ces nuances bien intéressantes autorisent différentes questions sur l'emploi etc. un peu comme celle de _prendre avec un grain de sel_ que j'ai posée. La curiosité est une question d'opportunisme ! Merci.

Answer (score 2):

En France, avant un examen, par exemple, il nous arrive de souhaiter "Merde" à la personne. Cette expression trouve son origine dans les pièces de théâtre, où, lorsqu'il y avait beaucoup de crottin de cheval, cela signifiait que la pièce avait eu beaucoup de succès, d'où le "Merde" que l'on peut dire aujourd'hui.